# How to prevent HTTPS reditrect on xampp for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have made virtual server for Laravel 5.4 project, it is laravel.cs  when I open homepage it opens http://laravel.cs but when I click on any other link it opens with HTTPs therefore getting 404 Error.

## .htacess file

```
# Laravel 5 Rewrites

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried by SSL engine OFF in xampp httpd-ssl-conf, but not worked

Comment: what is in your `config/session.php` `http_only`

Comment: yes it is hhtp_only=true

Comment: what middleware your route using check it like `php artisan route:list` in your terminal